# Install python egg without launching buildout

Tags: python, django, buildout, egg

I have installed my Django app with buildout and now I would like to add one more eggs.

But if I just add the egg in my buildout, and launch buildout, it will update all my eggs, which I don't want as I'm not sure it will work well with upgraded versions of other eggs.

I was wondering if there is a way to just add one egg in my app without launching buildout. My app is on shared hosting, so I dont have access to everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your new egg to the buildout, and run buildout with `-N`:

```
  -N

    Run in non-newest mode.  This is equivalent to the assignment
    buildout:newest=false.  With this setting, buildout will not seek
    new distributions if installed distributions satisfy it's
    requirements.
```

This means eggs will *not* be upgraded.

You may want to *pin* your egg versions; add a `[versions]` section where you name all your egg versions, and add a `versions = versions` entry in the `[buildout]` section. Add `newest = false` and `allow-picked-versions = false` as well to enforce the policy and require that *all* eggs have an entry in the versions section:

```ini
[buildout]
# other options
versions = versions
allow-picked-versions = false
newest = false

[versions]
Django = 1.5.5
South = 0.8.2
# etc.
```

Running with `allow-picked-versions = false` results in an error every time buildout comes across an egg you did not pin yet; keep adding eggs to the `[versions]` section until all eggs are pinned.